# Unable to resolve path to module 'react-dom/client' (import/no-unresolved)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I've upgraded my React Application to React 18. Everything works fine but I receive warning
`Unable to resolve path to module 'react-dom/client'`

Environment is:

- Node v16.15.0,
- react: 18.2.0,
- react-dom: 18.2.0
- @types/node: 16.11.8,
- @types/react": "^18.0.26

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';
import './index.scss';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Any suggestions please!

Comment: Seems to work here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-allen-s2x9e9?file=/src/index.js:36-83